# Nifi jolt transform for string manipulation

Tags: elasticsearch, etl, apache-nifi, jolt, data-ingestion

I have a json document which i need to apply jolt transform on, I appreciate any help.
Here is my json document.

```
{
    "name": "Wine Seller 1",
    "in_stock": "3800",
    "sold": "47",
    "products": [
    {
        "product_id":"001",
        "product_name":"Wine - Maipo Valle Cabernet",
        "description":"Aliquam augue q\uam, sollicitudin \nvitae, \"consectetuer\" \$100eget, rutrum at"
    },
    {
        "product_id":"002",
        "product_name":"Bacardi",
        "description":"Praesent blandit \lacinia erat. \n Vestibulum \"sed\" magna"
    },
.,
.'
.,
.
}
```

I want the output to remove all , \n, \t, from description and i want to keep all the \" there. like below

```
{
    "name": "Wine Seller 1",
    "in_stock": "3800",
    "sold": "47",
    "products": [
        {
            "product_id": "001",
            "product_name": "Wine - Maipo Valle Cabernet",
            "description": "Aliquam augue quam, sollicitudin vitae, \"consectetuer\" $100eget, rutrum at"
        },
        {
            "product_id": "002",
            "product_name": "Bacardi",
            "description": "Praesent blandit lacinia erat. Vestibulum \"sed\" magna"
        },
.,
.,
.,
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Joby, are you sure about the JSON input? Since those quoted values already cannot have single backslashes such as `q\uam`, `\$..` for a valid JSON ... Btw, there's no `\t` in the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can consecutively use ***split*** and ***join*** functions within **modify** transformation specs presuming you want to remove `\n` and `\t` combinations based on the JSON data after fixing it such as

```json
[
  { // split the by "description" values by \n
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "products": {
        "*": {
          "description": "=split('\n',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of "\n"s
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "products": {
        "*": {
          "description": "=join('',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // split the by "description" values by \t
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "products": {
        "*": {
          "description": "=split('\t',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of "\t"s
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "products": {
        "*": {
          "description": "=join('',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Or you can **simplify** that like this:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "products": {
        "*": {
          "description": "=split('\n',@(1,&))",
          "descriptio*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "products": {
        "*": {
          "description": "=split('\t',@(1,&))",
          "descriptio*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```